# Как правильно сделать туннель в Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Вот так все работает `ssh user@122.77.93.56 -p8022 -L 9042:localhost:9042`, но при этом захватывается полностью окно терминала. При этом туннель не сохраняется при перезапуске системы или закрытии терминала.

Как сделать также, но, чтобы это работало по умолчанию при включении комьпютера и не захватывало окно терминала ?

Comment: Связанный вопрос [How to reliably keep an SSH tunnel open?](https://superuser.com/q/37738/13868)

Answer (score 1):

Можно в crontab добавить что-то вроде

```
TUN = 'ssh user@122.77.93.56 -p8022 -L 9042:localhost:9042'

*/5 * * * * pgrep -f "$TUN" &>/dev/null || $TUN
```

Каждые 5 минут будет выполняться автоматическая проверка наличия туннеля, и если его нет - туннель будет снова подниматься (помогает также в случаях, когда соединение обрывается по таймауту). Чтобы туннель поднимался сразу при запуске системы, можно то же самое условие добавить вместе с `@reboot`

Вероятно, еще придется задать переменные `ServerAliveInterval` и `ServerAliveCountMax` в конфиге ssh, чтобы поддерживать подключение в активном состоянии

Comment: Не прокатывает. :( Тунель не поднимается в фоне по крону даже с ServerAliveInterval и ServerAliveCountMax. :( Делаю так: `TUN = 'ssh user@122.77.93.56 -p8022 -L 9042:localhost:9042 -o ServerAliveInterval=10000000 -o ServerAliveCountMax=10000000'
*/1 * * * * pgrep -f "$TUN" &>/dev/null || $TUN`

Answer (score 1):

[systemd сервис можно создать](https://gist.github.com/drmalex07/c0f9304deea566842490) на основе ssh или [autossh](https://gist.github.com/thomasfr/9707568). Полный [пример по шагам](https://francispereira.com/alway-connected-ssh-reverse-port-forwarding-with-systemd.html).

Comment: Пробовал, проблема возникает в том, что при открытии `ssh` в фоне, подключение переходит в пассивный режим и моя база (туннель именно к ней) перестает откликаться.

Comment: @faoxis очевидно, что ssh туннель как systemd сервис работает в общем случае, но какие параметры в ssh передать, чтобы в вашем конкретном случае ssh соединение жило это уже отдельный вопрос.

Comment: зачем мне тунель через который нельзя передавать параметры ?) Разве это не предполагается по умолчанию ?)

Comment: @faoxis: с чего вы взяли что параметры передавать нельзя? Ссылки содержат пару конфигураций -- вы естественно свои параметры можете передать.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону программ screen или tmux.  Так же есть выражение `nohup <command> &` Оно заставляет процесс игнорировать отключение пользователя и уводит процесс в background.  Crontab как watcher для вашего туннеля будет так-же неплохим решением.

Comment: `tmux` сохраняет сессию в `tmp`. После перезагрузки компьютера все придется делать с нуля.